# How to create TDS projects in Helix setup?

Tags: helix, tds, multisite

I am working on migrating an existing solution to Helix conventions. The existing solution has TDS projects for Master, Content and Media. How do I set up TDS projects in the newly refactored solution following Helix conventions?

Comment: That sounds pretty broad. What aspects of TDS project setup are you wondering about, exactly?

Comment: Basically I am looking for some understanding on how to set up TDS projects in a Helix setup? For example we are not using transforms for config files. We are using TDS file replacement to deploy environment specific config files. Secondly, how do we go about syncing items? Does all of that remain the same or would change now that we are implementing Helix conventions? And also, in which layer of solution should I besetting up TDS projects? Foundation, Feature or Project?

Comment: Have you seen [**this repository**](https://github.com/HedgehogDevelopment/Habitat/tree/TDS-latest)? It contains an example project structure with TDS that follows the Helix guidelines.

Comment: You create a TDS project for each feature, foundation and project. The code and serialization needs to be separate for each project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried to find a commit when Habitat when it used to be TDS (https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat) to no avail. But what you want to do is create a TDS project for each Feature/Foundation/Project. In the same way that their is a Unicorn serialization folder for each Feature/Foundation/Project, you would do the same TDS.

Comment: Hmmm...that does make sense. It would need much work to set up initially but I think I like the idea of syncing only what I need to.

Comment: I like using the Yeoman generator to create my Helix projects for me. I use Unicorn, but it will do TDS for your needs. https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-prodigious-helix

Comment: The Habitat TDS repo can be found here. https://github.com/HedgehogDevelopment/Habitat/tree/TDS-latest